# equivalent of windows batch echo off in linux

Tags: bash, wget

I need to hide content of .sh script and only show echo "messajes". The equivalent of windows batch: **@echo off**

Examples:

```
echo "Download..."
wget http://mypage.com/files/file.zip
echo "Ending..."
sed -e '/^#/d' file2.tar.gz | sed 's/^/./' | sort -u > out
echo "Done"
```

I need this result in console:

```
Download..
Ending..
Done
```

Comment: `@echo off` is there to hide the commands themselves being printed but that's the default in `bash` (and AFAIK there isn't even any option to activate the DOS behavior either).

Comment: wget -quiet http://mypage.com/files/file.zip

Comment: Thanks @Kamaraj. That's what I was looking. Put your complete answer to select it as correct

Comment: @Kamaraj the question has been reopened, please post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this command...

wget -quiet file.zip